# Play TypeSafe Activator fails to start - IllegalArgumentException "Failed to download new template catalog properties"

Tags: playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

Moving from play 2.2.x to latest activator last night. Downloaded minimal 1.2.10, extracted it in program file (x86)\typesafe... and put the directory into the system path variable. cloned my repository, and when i executed `activator run` it downloaded the required modules and my app is up and running. All great so far. `run` works!

Then I tried to create a new app, and activator fails, with the following trace:

> Checking for a newer version of Activator (current version 1.2.10)...
>    ... our current version 1.2.10 looks like the latest.
> Found previous process id: 9632
> FOUND REPO = activator-local @ file:////C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Typesafe/activator-1.2.10-minimal/repository
> Play server process ID is 9760
> [info] play - Application started (Prod)
> [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /127.0.0.1:8888
> [info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
> [WARN] [10/30/2014 10:47:13.972] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [ActorSystem(default)] Failed to download new template ca
> talog properties: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file 'C:\Users\admin\.activator\1.2.10\templates\in
> dex.db_6e0565f0c8826b17.tmp' is a directory.
> [ERROR] [10/30/2014 10:47:13.972] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://default/user/template-cache] Could not find a te
> mplate catalog. (activator.templates.repository.RepositoryException: We don't have C:\Users\admin\.activator\1.2.10\templates\cache.
> properties with an index hash in it, even though we should have downloaded one
> activator.templates.repository.RepositoryException: We don't have C:\Users\admin\.activator\1.2.10\templates\cache.properties with a
> n index hash in it, even though we should have downloaded one
>         at activator.cache.TemplateCacheActor.preStart(TemplateCacheActor.scala:184)
>         at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:470)
>         at activator.cache.TemplateCacheActor.aroundPreStart(TemplateCacheActor.scala:25)
>         at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
>         at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
>         at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
>         at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
>         at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
>         at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
>         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>         at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

I've taken a look at several similar issues on SO and elsewhere. I've deleted .activator directory and retried, I've tried this process from behind a proxy and not, as well as offline (surely offline should work!), but it consistently gives the above error. `activator ui` gives the same error. I'm stuck and any suggestions would be appreciated. (Edit. tried with full activator download, rather than minimal, and I get the same error.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for reasons it might be impossible to create or access 'C:\Users\admin.activator\1.2.10\templates\in
dex.db_6e0565f0c8826b17.tmp' ... maybe a permissions issue?
The failed check is for "is a directory" but that also fails if it just doesn't exist or can't be accessed.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I moved the activator directory out from program files (x86) to another location, and it started working.

Comment: I subsequently had to set permissions on the child objects under the activator directory to be full control to Everyone. Have not fine-tuned this.